# Find the constant term in the development of $(2x^2 + \frac{1}{4x})^{99}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling with the following problem:

Find the constant term in the development of $(2x^2 + \frac{1}{4x})^{99}$

This is a combinatorics problem where I should find what the constant term is when $x^0$.

I have made the following developments:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n=99}  \binom {99} {k} 2^{n-k}x^{2(n-k)} \times (\frac{1}{4x})^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n=99} \binom {99} {k} 2^{99-k}x^{(198-2k)} \times \frac{1}{2^{2k}x^k}$$

This sum terms could be written together like this:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n=99} \binom {99} {k} \frac{2^{99-k}x^{(198-2k)}}{{2^{2k}x^k}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n=99} \binom {99} {k} 2^{99-3k}x^{(198-3k)}$$

This gives me that $x^0$ when $198-3k = 0$ But this is the wrong answer....

My textbook says that the constant term will be when $3k-99 = 0$ which gives that $k = 33$ and $\binom {99} {33} \times 2^{99-198}$

Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected that.

Comment: So what was your answer for the constant term?

Comment: Your textbook chose to list the terms in different order, $(a+b)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n-k}$, whereas you took $(a+b)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}b^{k}$. By the symmetry of binomial coefficients, both are the same.

Comment: Yes that is probably the case, but I should still be able to come up with the right answer... :)

Comment: Your answer _is_ right. That's the point. (I suppose when you expanded it, you got $\binom{99}{66}2^{-99}$, if not, you have a mistake somewhere indeed.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, exactly right!

Comment: Okok My bad! I will study this some more then. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Easier way is to see that the constant term is created by having 33 of $x^2$ and 66 of $\frac{1}{x}$ from the whole 99 terms. There are in general ${99 \choose 33}$ ways of finding this product. The answer then is 
$${99 \choose 33}2^{-99}
$$

Comment: Yes This is the correct answer according to my textbook. And I understand your method (smart!), but I would also like to know where my error was. Thank you!

Comment: In your answer, you get $k=66$ and then your answer is right!

Comment: So the correct answer could also be written $\binom {99} {66} 2 ^{-99}?$

Comment: Exactly right. I should have looked at your answer more carefully and wait for you to correct it yourself instead of answering it! You had it!

Comment: Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You found that the constant term was the $k=66$ term, which for your setup is correct; you get a coefficient of

$$\binom{99}{66}2^{-99}\;,$$

which is equal to $$\binom{99}{99-66}2^{-99}=\binom{99}{33}2^{-99}\;.$$

Don’t forget that $\dbinom{n}k=\dbinom{n}{n-k}$ always.

If you switch the rôles of the two terms before you apply the binomial theorem, you get the result directly:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(2x^2+\frac1{4x}\right)^{99}&=\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{99}k(2x^2)^k\left(\frac1{4x}\right)^{99-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{99}k2^{k-2(99-k)}x^{2k-(99-k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{99}k2^{3k-198}x^{3k-99}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so the constant term is the $k=33$ term, whose coefficient is

$$\binom{99}{33}4^{-99}\;.$$

Comment: It's $(2x^2 + \frac{1}{4x})^{99}$, not $2x$.

Comment: @Brian : You shouldn't answer on MSE at 6 in the morning, your brain is not working yet :P haha... yeah, look at your typo brother.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brian! I will look into this. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Lukas: You’re welcome.